# datatable without specifying columns

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I am implementing datatable in my project using instruction from https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Now I have implemented same jquery code like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

but its not working in my project and gives the error of :

```
DataTables warning: ********** Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

but when I specify **columns** in jquery like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php",
         "columns": [
                { "data": "id"},
                { "data": "item" },
                { "data": "name" }
         ],
    } );
} );
```

then it works perfectly, So whats the issue here, why I can not use it without specifying columns ?

**Ajax Response :**

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 57,
  "recordsFiltered": 57,
  "data": [
    [
      1,
      "item1",
      "name1"
    ],
    [
      2,
      "item2",
      "name2"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post your json response from server processing.php? Usually this happens when the value of the corresponding key (0) is null or undefined.

Comment: information added

Comment: If this really is the AJAX response, wrap the numbers into quotes as well., i.e `"2",` not `2,` ...

Comment: still same error

Comment: What´s the status? Care to accept the answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you are accessing an array of objects instead of a two dimensional array.

Datatables default behavior is accepting data in this format:

```
[
    [ "row 1, cell 1", "row 1, cell 2", "row 1, cell 3" ],
    [ "row 2, cell 2", "row 2, cell 2", "row 2, cell 3" ]
]
```

If you use a different data source format, as I believe you do, you must specify the columns so datatables can map them.

You can find more information [here](https://datatables.net/blog/2011-05-01)

If possible, provide your json response to check if this is the case.

Ok, I can see your response now, and it works if you wrap your ids in double quotes.

Try this - create a file named response.php with this content:

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 57,
  "recordsFiltered": 57,
  "data": [
    [
      "1",
      "item1",
      "name1"
    ],
    [
      "2",
      "item2",
      "name2"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Create another file named test.php with this content:

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "./response.php"
    } );
} );
</script>
</body>
```

Upload both files to your server and test it - it works.

Comment: Update: This blog post was written before the release of DataTables 1.10, and therefore does not make use of the new API or features used by the latest DataTables releases, in particular the columns.render and columns.data options. This post is left for historical reference; please refer to the manual for information on the current release of DataTables.

Comment: @Er.KT, the blog post may be outdated, but the knowledge is still applicable. The changes is in this case merely cosmetic. If you look close to the example you are linking to yourself, the example *is* using 1.10.x and is based on an [**array of array of strings datasource**](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php)